# Vanishing of the local étale cohomology sheaf (?)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, brauer-groups

Let $X$ be a locally noetherian regular scheme, and let $Z$ be a closed subscheme of $X$ whose codimension $d > 0$ at every point.
Let $U$ be the complement of $Z$ in $X$.
For a sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ on $X$ (étale topology), define $\Gamma_Z(\mathscr{F})$ to be the sheaf sending $V$ to  $\ker ( \mathscr{F}(V) \to \mathscr{F}(V \cap U) )$.
Let $\mathscr{H}_Z^*$ be the right derived functor of $\Gamma_Z(-)$.

How can we show the following?:

> 1. $\mathscr{H}_Z^p(\mathbb{G}_m) = 0$ for $p = 0,2$, and
> 2. If $d > 1$, then $\mathscr{H}_Z^1(\mathbb{G}_m) = 0$.
>    If $d = 1$, then $\mathscr{H}_Z^1(\mathbb{G}_m) = \sum_Y (i_Y)_* \mathbb{Z}$,
>    where $Y$ runs through the irreducible components of $Z$, and $i_Y$ is the inclusion $Y \to X$.

Here is what I have tried:

Let $H^*_Z(X, -)$ be the right derived functor of the functor $\mathscr{F} \to \Gamma_Z(\mathscr{F})(X)$.
I can show that $H_Z^0(X, \mathbb{G}_m) = 0 $, and a statement for $H_Z^1(X, \mathbb{G}_m)$ similar to the second statement of the highlighted paragraph.

The groups $H_Z^p$ seem to be related to the sheaves $\mathscr{H}_Z^p$, so it seems to lead the proof of the highlighted statements.
But I can't show it.

This is the equation 6.3, 6.4, 6.5 of Grothendieck's "Le groupe de Brauer III".
He said that it is trivial, but I can't show it.

Comment: What have you tried? If I read correctly, Grothendieck explains how to start in 6.1 and 6.2 (although the argument may not be complete). Namely: you have a LES $H^p_Z(X,-) \rightarrow H^p(X,-) \rightarrow H^p(X \backslash Z,-) \rightarrow H^{p+1}_Z(X,-)$. At least for $p \leq 1$ and $\mathbb{G}_m$, everything can be made explicit. Then use the spectral sequence to recover some information about $\mathcal{H}_Z^{\cdot}$ from $H^{\cdot}_Z$.